# Как настроить отображение числа в Label?

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Доброго времени суток. Ситуация такая: есть NSTimer и UILabel, который показывает значение таймера. Вот код:

```
- (IBAction)start:(id)sender
{
self->timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(timer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)timer
{
    y = y-1;

[_timerLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f seconds", y]];

}
```

Но в Label выводятся значения такого вида:

5.000000 seconds

Как это исправить? Спасибо за помощь

Comment: а нужно, чтоб отображались целые секунды?

Comment: Совершенно верно, чтоб не было нолей

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно как минимум двумя способами это сделать:

```
//1. вывести 0 знаков после запятой
[_timerLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f seconds", round(y)]];
//2. преобразовать в int
[_timerLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d seconds", (int) round(y)]];
```

в принципе, если вы четко уверены что у вас там целое или близкое к нему с большей стороны  число(не 4.999999, а 5.1), то можно и без round, правда тогда вопрос зачем вам float

Comment: Все работает, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
[_timerLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d seconds", (int)y]];
```

и почитайте на досуге:
[вот это](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html)

Comment: все-таки лучше округлять, а то вот этот лог NSLog(@"test %d",(int)4.9999); выводит test 4

Comment: @aknew, топикстартеру как я понял не критично, но cогласен с Вами